# Matrix Decomposition and Collect

Tags: matrix

I am looking to decompose a matrix in terms of a sum of matrices with the same coefficients, i want something in this form :

$ m1=
    \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + 2a + 3 & 1 \\ 
 2a & a^2
\end{pmatrix}
=a^2\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0\\ 
 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
+a\begin{pmatrix}
 2& 0\\ 
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
 3& 1\\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

I tried to use `Collect[m1,a]` but it collects the terms inside the matrix instead of giving a sum of matrices.

Comment: Please, add always copyable code to your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
decompose[m_,a_]:=With[{max = Max @ Exponent[m, a]},
    terms = SeriesCoefficient[m, {a, 0, #}]& /@ Range[0,max];
    a^Range[0,max] . MatrixForm/@terms
]
```

Then:

```
    decompose[{{3+2 a+a^2,1},{2 a,a^2}}, a] //TeXForm
```

> $a^2 \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)+a \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  2 & 0 \\
>  2 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)+\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  3 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Very nice (+1).  This could be useful in a number of linear algebra environments.